# What data types are supported in SQL CE 3.5 (Windows Phone Mango)

Tags: database, sql-server-ce, geospatial, windows-phone-7

What datatypes are supported in SQL CE 3.5? Specifically can you use the Geography/Geometry types?

Comment: After a lot of digging (why I can't find any documenation is beyond me) I'm fairly sure the answer is no :(

Comment: Windows Phone Mango SQL Server Compact version is 3.5!

Comment: Thanks, that was the other bit of info I was stuggling to track down

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Geospatial types are not supported.
Only Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition (SQL CE) data types are supported.
You can find a list of supported types at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424(SQL.110).aspx